# Looking for help translating four words for a business motto please

Tags: translation-check

I'm in the process of setting up a new reiki business and would like to have my motto in Latin. I have already translated the words with a dictionary and Google so just wanted to make sure that what I've got is right please?

Compassion, Love, Gratitude, Community. 
I have translated it as Misericordia, Amor, Gratia Cantus, Civitas. 
Apparently the word gratitude translates to Grace Singing, is this true? 
Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: The idiotic machine has apparently "corrected" (grati)tude to "tune".

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you came up with is not bad at all. You only need to leave 'Cantus' after 'Gratia' out since singing does not make any sense here. 'Gratiae' (that's the plural as 'gratia' as is rather means favoritism, as Figulus pointed out) alone does indeed mean 'gratitude' - that's where the English word comes from!
'Civitas' however rather means something like citizenship or state, so I would rather use `communio` which is identical to 'community' in its meaning.

Comment: I like your suggestion of *communio* for community. I'd say it's much better than *civitas*.

Comment: I recommend changing *gratia* to the plural if you want it to mean gratitude rather than, say, favoritism. *Misericordia, Amor, Gratiae, Communio*.

Comment: I totally agree, I'll change that.